# R: How can I use dplyr to create a lag whose reference value is dynamic?

Tags: r, dplyr, lag

Maybe the title is a little bit vague but I didn't know how to better describe it. Suppose the following table/column is given:

```
tab0 <- data.frame(month = c(1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12))
```

What I would love to achieve by using dplyr is the following table:

```
tab1 <- data.frame(month = c(1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12), group = c(1, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4))
```

A month is assigned to a group in a way such that there is a maximum time lag (within a group) of 2 months. This is only an example, in the end I want to apply it to much more data and use days instead of months. I hope it's clear what I am after.

Answer (score 1):

```
# example dataframe
tab0 <- data.frame(month = c(1, 3, 4, 7, 9, 12))

# input your lag
lag = 2

# create group
tab0$group = 1 + (tab0$month - tab0$month[1]) %/% (lag + 1)

# see updated daatset
tab0

#   month group
# 1     1     1
# 2     3     1
# 3     4     2
# 4     7     3
# 5     9     3
# 6    12     4
```

The group number is calculated as follows: For each row we get the distance between the current month and the first month. Then we divide the result with 3 (your lag of 2 plus 1) and we keep the integer part of the division. Finally we add 1 to the result.

Comment: @ AntoniosK Thank you for your suggestion. How would you adjust it for the case of lag = 90 (days) and tab0 <- data.frame(day = c(0:90, 100:200))? Thank you

Comment: That should work `lag = 90;
tab0$group = 1 + (tab0$day - tab0$day[1]) %/% (lag + 1)`. The first day here is 0 and not 1 though.

Comment: Thanks again. Maybe I didn't frame the question clear enough but in the code you provided, group 2 starts at day=100 and goes through until day=180. But what I prefer would be to consider that day starts at 100 (and not 90) and so group 2 should cover all days from 100 to 190. The starting point is not supposed to be a simple multiple of the lag but is reset for each group.